# Maximum amplitude of FFT data

Tags: matlab

I need help in finding the maximum amplitude of an FFT signal.

Say I perform FFT on an audio file and get a column of complex numbers, how can i extract the maximum amplitude and its index from the FFT signal?? 
I tried using the "max" syntax but i get an error: ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Would appreciate some help.. Thanx

This is the code I've used

```
[wave,fs]=wavread('c scale fast.wav'); % read file into memory */
%sound(wave,fs); % see what it sounds like */
t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs; % and get sampling frequency */


figure(90);
          subplot(2,1,1)
          %plot(t,wave)
          plot(t,abs(wave))
          title('Wave File')
          ylabel('Amplitude')
          xlabel('Length (in seconds)')


L = length(wave);
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(wave,NFFT)/L;
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);


% Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
        subplot(2,1,2)
        plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
        title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)')
        xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
        ylabel('|Y(f)|')

 A = max(Y)
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: this is the error = "??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Comment: are you able to plot the wav data?

Comment: Yes, the time domain and frequency domain plots are perfect. Im having trouble in writing a code to find the maximum amplitude in the FFT plot.

Comment: Well but then again, my FFT is not integer numbers and hence the error....

Comment: It still gives the same error :(. I think its because my FFT is in decimal points and not integers. So though its complex because of the fact that its in decimal Im getting the error.

Comment: The `clear max` seems to do the trick for this particular code. But doesnt work for another coding...

Comment: if you name a variable in your workspace `max` then matlab assumes that in a statement max(ii) you are attempting to index entry ii in array max.... you override the default meaning of `max`

Comment: not sure why you get different results for different codes...

Comment: Ok I finally got it. I apparently had another variable called `max` and so the error. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The fft returns a complex number. You should use the absolute Value to find the maximum:

```
[maxY,indexOfMaxY] = max(abs(Y));
```